# Delete request not working in Postman for express.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, postman

I have identified the error. However, I do not know why this line of code is causing the error.

```
 if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
  return res.status(404).json({ error: "no such comment" });
 }
```

when I removed the above lines, the DEL request worked. My new question is, what's wrong with the above lines?

Thank you so, so much.

[Update] The error is that this method is deprecated.

---

Currently attempting to store comments in Mango DB by using express js as the backend. However, the DEL request is not working when I test it with postman. The server just stops and Postman returns 'Error: read ECONNRESET'.

I asked gpt and it doesn't help either.

Any help appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment Controller

```
const Comment = require("../models/Comment");


// delete a comment
const deleteComment = async (req, res) => {
  const {id} = req.params;
  
  if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
    return res.status(404).json({ error: "no such comment" });
  }
  try {
    const comment = await Comment.findOneAndDelete({ _id: id });
    if (!comment) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "no such comment" });
    }
    res.status(200).json(comment);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Error deleting comment" });
  }
};

module.exports = {
  createComment,
  getComments,
  deleteComment,
};
```

Comment Route

```
const express = require('express');
const {
  createComment, 
  getComments,
  deleteComment,
} = require('../controllers/commentController');

const router = express.Router();


// GET comments for a specific post
router.get('/posts/:id/comments', getComments);

// CREATE a new comment for a specific post
router.post('/posts/:id/comments', createComment);

router.delete('/:id', deleteComment)

module.exports = router;
```

Server.js

```
require('dotenv').config()

const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const commentsRoute = require('./routes/commentsRoute');
const postsRoute = require('./routes/postsRoute')

// middleware
app.use(express.json())

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
  console.log(req.path, req.method)
  next()
})

// routes
// mount the comment routes
app.use('/api', commentsRoute);
app.use('/api', postsRoute);

// connect to db
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
  .then(()=>{
    // listen for requests
    app.listen(process.env.PORT, ()=>{
      console.log('connected to db and listening on port', process.env.PORT)
    })
  })
  .catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error)
  })
```

Comment: Do you have something like `router.delete('/:id', deleteComment)` in your `posts` router?

Comment: Your catch block does not return a response `catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Error deleting comment" }); // missing return here?
  }`

Comment: After your update: you are not returning anything if your check throws exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with this?

```
// import this
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;


if(!ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
    return res.status(404).json({ error: "no such comment" });
}
```